# Is it possible to receive files on memory card during wifi direct transfer ? Is it possible to change wifi direct send/receive settings ?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, settings, file-transfer, wifi-direct

Is it possible to receive files on memory card during wifi direct transfer ? Is it possible to change wifi direct send/receive settings ?

Case is like I need a file from another android phone to my android phone but device storage memory is low against size of file but have sufficient of space in memory card, but when the transfer starts a file is copied only to the device.

**EDIT** : Device is not rooted

Comment: If your device is rooted, DirectoryBind might be a possible solution (letting a directory from your SDCard appear to be an internal one).

Comment: Sorry but device are not rooted, updated question accordingly thax for your help.

Comment: Can anyone tell what is this "bumped to homepage" by community?

Answer (score 1):

ES File Explorer used to be by choice for Android phones rooted or not, until the development was lagging and not current.

[FX FileExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx) is to me, the best file manager out there. Has everything ES has and more but is also maintained often, updated and secure.  I don't 100% remember why I stopped using the former, but I do recall WebDav, FTP, was not great amongst other things. Read "[A Short Story of A Fallen King](https://www.xda-developers.com/es-file-explorer-a-short-story-of-a-fallen-king/)" and the comments. You will read similar sentiments among other users.

Forgot to mention: FX protects your privacy:

- No advertisements
- No tracking of user activity: FX does not ever "phone home"
- Built by NextApp, Inc., a US corporation founded in 2002; all proprietary code was developed in-house.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to transfer huge files (in GBs) between my rooted phone and unrooted Nexus 7 tablet.

When doing a Wi-Fi based transfer (i.e. using send option), ES File Explorer asks for destination in the target device and I can choose where ever I want (in the context of the question, I can choose a path leading to a folder in my external card).

Comment: File send using share or send in ES File Explorer ? My both device are not connected in same wifi network.

Comment: Try FX Explorer. You will not regret it.